# Calculating $e^{3x} \pmod{27}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am following some notes that say that $\exp(3x) = 1 + 3x + \frac{9}{2}x^2 + \frac{9}{2}x^3 = 1 +3x+18x^2+18x^3 \pmod{27}$

I can't understand this. Firstly why do we stop the expansion after 4 terms? And secondly I don't see why $ \frac{9}{2}x^2 + \frac{9}{2}x^3 = 18x^2+18x^3 \pmod{27}$

Could someone please explain it to me? I wish to follow the same method for $\log(1+5x) \pmod{5^4} $

Thanks in advance

Comment: You stop it after 4 terms, because in the rest of the expansion, the coefficients are a multiple of 27 (to be checked), and hence are equal to 0 when taken modulo 27.

Comment: In fact you stop after the first three terms, I think, since the fourth one's already zero modulo $\;27\;$ ...

Comment: Modulo 27, 9 is 36.  So $9/2 = 18 \pmod{27}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$e^{3x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(3x)^k}{k!}=1+3x+\frac{9x^2}2+\underbrace{\frac{9x^3}2}_{=\frac{27}{3!}}+\underbrace{27\left(\frac{x^4}{8}+\frac{3x^5}{40}+\ldots\right)}_{=0\pmod{27}}$$

and now check that

$$\frac12=2^{-1}=14\pmod{27}\implies \frac92=9\cdot14=18\pmod{27}$$

so we finally get

$$e^{3x}=1+3x+18x^2+18x^3\pmod{27}$$

Comment: It's important to have some context in which this makes sense.  Formally we can take the expression $\exp(3x)$ for $x$ some integer, and observe that the rational numbers that arise in the series expansion can be taken modulo $27$ in a well-defined way.  Then where the rational numbers *converge* to $\exp(3x)$ on the real number line (a Cauchy sequence), the residues mod $27$ simply stabilize after the fourth term (partial sums).

Comment: Indeed so @hardmath, yet I'm supposing the OP has some context for this...

Comment: @DonAntonio , you still need the $18x^3$ term , right?

Comment: Yes @neofoxmulder. I forgot to add it in the last line, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ 
the  terms of degree more than 3 are multiples of 27